# Display Tag : Showing records with Partial List

Tags: java, pagination, displaytag

I have one admin interface in JAVA, where admin can view and manage the multiple users(500-2000).

I am using the [display tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) to display the users details. For that i am sending the full list(all users details) and the page takes very much time to load.

Is there some best alternative for this scenario. Can we use display tag to work with partial list(paging indexes, 1-10 then 11-20 and so on).

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
<display:table ... partialList="true">
```

Read more here:
http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html